# ERROR: Too many records for the output file SAS

Tags: sas, proc-sql

```
proc export data =S.N_20220213
 outfile = '/sas/Pro.xlsx'
 dbms = XLSX
 replace;
 GETNAMES=YES;
run;
```

Unable to export due to
Error: Too many records for the output file SAS

Please let me know how i can create the file

Comment: Does your data have more than 1,048,576 records?

Comment: Yes it does have '7189000'

Comment: https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/132527-is-this-like-putting-10-pounds-of-flour-in-a-5-pound-sack

Comment: Excel files have a limit of 1 million rows. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3

Comment: Thank you so much for the references. Appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

Most probably you are trying to export a table that has > 1,048,576 records, which is too much for Excel to handle.

Do you need it as an `.xlsx` anyway? As stated in this [SAS Topic](https://communities.sas.com/t5/SASware-Ballot-Ideas/have-proc-export-determine-if-record-count-is-too-large-for/idi-p/475640), Excel is not a good data file format.  Choose an appropriate file format for the task in hand. CSV, XML or even JSON.

A csv file is only limited by available disk storage.

```
proc export
  data = S.N_20220213
  outfile = 'C:\Users\kermit\pro.csv'
  dbms = csv
  replace
;
run;
```